# Mulitfactor authentication with conditional access in Azure Active Directory for custom app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

We have a custom web application which is hosted on a Hetzner server. The users get redirected to Azure AD to login when they want to access the site. Our goal is to enable MFA only for this application but it does not work. There is only normal login but no need for second factor.

We have added a custom cloud app in Azure AD and configured a policy for this app with MFA activated (no matter which client, location, etc.). When MFA is activated globally it works and the users have to enable/use second factor to get logged in by Azure AD. But with the policy it does not work. 
The What-If tool says, that the policy is used. The Azure AD has a P2 license and for testing one user also has a Cloud App Security License.

Does anyone know why the conditional access rule is not taken into account?

Comment: Could you please have a check with my answer. It works at my side. Or, you may share some screenshots for further investigating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested at my side, and everything was fine. Here is my conditional access setting:

1. Select users and groups

[image]

2. Choose the application

[image]

3. Set the grant access control

[image]

4. Enable the policy

[image]

Finally, when I tried to sign in to the web application, I will be asked to provide additional information.  But, for other apps (Azure portal, Office portal and so on), I can still directly sign in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed description. The settings look the same as we have done it. Unfortunately I cannot share screenshosts as I do not have access (it's the AAD of a customer). Is the App "AD_MFA" hosted in Azure? Our webapp is running outside of Azure. And which AAD version and licenses do you have in place?

Comment: 1. It has nothing to do with the platform that the application is hosted, as long as you registered the application in Azure AD.   2. I have Azure AD Premium P2

Comment: Just to be sure: with registered you mean added as app?
It can be selected under cloud apps when adding the conditional access policy. The redirect and login works. The only missing piece is that Azure AD requires MFA for the logins.

Comment: I have set up a test AAD and registered a new app. I have used the sample node app and MFA with conditional access works as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found a solution for our web application. 
Our application uses response_type code and used scope user.read when redirecting to Azure AD. We have added openid to scope and now the conditional access policy is executed.

I don't know why this fixes the issue, but maybe someone also falls into this trap and at least finds a solution.